# Fern Planar Objectdetection OpenCV

Tags: opencv, object-detection, feature-extraction

i'm trying to run the planar object detection algorithm FERN. Here is the code i'm using and my question is if somebody could tell me what is my fault und how i've got to train the Ferns right.

At first i've get the keypoints of the referenceimage with the help of the FAST feature detector. When this is done i initialize a FernDescriptorMatcher und add the image with the keypoints to it and call the train function. Something wrong?

```
FernDescriptorMatcher fern;
fern.add(images,keypoints);
fern.train();
```

After that i load another image with the object i've trained in it and get the keypoints so that i can match them by calling the match function.

```
fast.detect(testimage,keypoints_testimage);
fern.match(testimage,keypoints_testimage,correspondence);
```

What i do not understand is why the match function tooks the same time then the train function and there is no feasible result. So how du i use the FernDescriptorMatcher class correct?

Can somebody tell me how to use it right?

Comment: What's the result of `fern.match(testimage,keypoints_testimage,correspondence);`? Does it crash, or what happens?

Comment: No it takes some time to match, but returns no feasible result.